# List<> object in WP7 Local Database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to store a List<> object in WP7 Local Database?

Comment: I have a listbox with checkbox item. I want all the checked item to be added in a List<> and store in Local database.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: go every items in listbox and check weather its checked item or not.If  it is checked, add to List object

Comment: @stay_hungry: Check my answer. Simple Linq

Comment: @Matt Lacey I am using WP7 Local database!

Comment: Do you mean SQL CE? There are lots of databases which can run "locally" on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<CheckBox> lcb = myListBox.Items.OfType<CheckBox>()
                              .Where(c => c.IsChecked == true).ToList();
```

I used `OfType` instead of `Cast` because `OfType` will work even if there a single checkbox item or all items are checkboxes.

In case to `Cast` it will give error if even a single item is not checkbox.

Comment: `Where(c => c.IsChecked) ` or `Where(c => c.Checked)` ..?

Comment: List<CheckBox> is showing error.

Comment: what is this "c" in the above example?

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal Can you explain elaborately the above example?

Comment: @Sana "c" is the lambda expressions

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal: Thanks for the answer. I have no idea about Lambda expressions before. Can you explain elaborately the above example?

Comment: Do i need to declare the Lambda expression somewhere?

Comment: I have 3 listbox like this: <ListBox Name="bird" ItemsSource="{Binding birdCollection}" Margin="6,-10,-1,2" Width="416" Height="432">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Width="405" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="#FF333333" FontSize="26"/> 
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

Comment: And I want to store the Checkbox checked items into WP7 Local database as List<> object. How do I get this?

Comment: @Sana: In my answer i have picked listbox items where items are CheckBox using `myListBox.Items.OfType<CheckBox>()`. This returned say 5 items. Then `.Where(c => c.IsChecked)` checkes out of those 5 which one is checked. If checked, puts in a list using `.ToList()`. After all iteration, puts that list into `List<CheckBox> lcb`

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal: Thanks a lot! Now I got the idea but I am getting error with this ".Where(c => c.IsChecked)"

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Is there any assembly which I need to add?

Comment: System.Linq (for OfType, Where, ToList), System.Collections.Generic (for List<CheckBox>), System.Windows.Controls (for CheckBox),

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Can you please tell me how to insert "lcb" into wp7 local database? I have tried but its not working!

Comment: Its a list of controls. How can you put that in database?